# Get specific data from Salesbinder API JSON to a Google sheet

Tags: json, api, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hi what I'm trying to do is get the data from a Salesbinder invoice API (Invoice # is taken from Sheet2 Cell A1)  output the data to a Google sheet (sheet Cell A2)
here's the code i'm using to get data from Salesbinder API

```
function fetching() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var InvNumber = sheet2.getRange('A1').getValue();
  var USERNAME = 'APIKey';
  var PASSWORD = 'x';
  
  var url = 'https://mydomain.salesbinder.com/api/2.0/documents.json?documentNumber='+InvNumber+'&contextId=5';
  var headers = {
    "Authorization": "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(USERNAME + ':' + PASSWORD)
  };

 
  let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { headers });
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());

}
```

The result I get from the data is like this

{"document":[{"document_number":8542,"name":"VIOLET BEARINGS","context_id":5,"total_cost":7213.03,"total_tax":415.45,"total_tax2":0,"total_price":8309.08,"total_transactions":0,"issue_date":"2022-12-13T00:00:00+00:00","expiry_date":null,"shipping_address":"(Same as above)","date_sent":null,"shipped_percent":null,"status_id":9,"public_note":"","attention":"GLEN","payment_terms":"","id":"0b24e8d2-e7cc-4441-abd7-337c8a2c6cf1","customer_id":"5b0d881b-6a88-46e5-998c-06330a8e0006","user_id":"5b0d75b3-e9cc-4899-bf99-77610a8e0006","associated_document_id":"","created":"2022-12-13T21:21:43+00:00","modified":"2022-12-21T16:01:04+00:00","status":{"id":9,"name":"unpaid"},"context":{"id":5,"name":"invoice"},"customer":{"id":"5b0d881b-6a88-46e5-998c-06330a8e0006","name":"TestClient","customer_number":1889,"billing_address_1":"Add1","billing_address_2":"Add2","billing_city":"TestCity","billing_region":"TestLoc","billing_postal_code":"TestPost","billing_country":"CANADA","shipping_address_1":"Add1","shipping_address_2":"Add2","shipping_city":"TestCity","shipping_region":"TestLoc","shipping_postal_code":"TestPost","shipping_country":"CANADA"},"user":{"first_name":"test","last_name":"test"},"document_items":[{"id":"0ea11906-f197-4eb4-971e-715d4dc77ab2","name":"B-0832","document_id":"0b24e8d2-e7cc-4441-abd7-337c8a2c6cf1","item_id":null,"unit_id":4,"service_category_id":"5dc2f6d2-27e0-4dac-a2b7-39080a8e0008","description":"JGE/H/K DOOR GASKET","quantity":8,"quantity_partially_received":0,"quantity_partially_shipped":0,"tax":5,"tax2":0,"discount_percent":0,"cost":38.1,"price":43.81,"discounted_price":0,"weight":2,"modified":"2022-12-21T16:01:04+00:00","created":"2022-12-15T15:43:57+00:00","item_variations_location_id":null,"item_variation_data":null,"delete":false,"item":null},{"id":"2b7e9376-ed70-4e75-95c9-6237aad8cfc0","name":"B-0770","document_id":"0b24e8d2-e7cc-4441-abd7-337c8a2c6cf1","item_id":null,"unit_id":4,"service_category_id":"5dc2f6d2-27e0-4dac-a2b7-39080a8e0008","description":"MAIN BEARING JGE/H/K","quantity":8,"quantity_partially_received":0,"quantity_partially_shipped":0,"tax":5,"tax2":0,"discount_percent":0,"cost":282.73,"price":325.14,"discounted_price":0,"weight":6,"modified":"2022-12-21T16:01:04+00:00","created":"2022-12-15T15:43:57+00:00","item_variations_location_id":null,"item_variation_data":null,"delete":false,"item":null},{"id":"391c2ec1-e02d-4390-9a10-429c2ea460fc","name":"B-2082","document_id":"0b24e8d2-e7cc-4441-abd7-337c8a2c6cf1","item_id":null,"unit_id":4,"service_category_id":"5dc2f6d2-27e0-4dac-a2b7-39080a8e0008","description":"ROD BEARING JGE/H/K","quantity":8,"quantity_partially_received":0,"quantity_partially_shipped":0,"tax":5,"tax2":0,"discount_percent":0,"cost":282.73,"price":325.14,"discounted_price":0,"weight":5,"modified":"2022-12-21T16:01:04+00:00","created":"2022-12-15T15:43:57+00:00","item_variations_location_id":null,"item_variation_data":null,"delete":false,"item":null},{"id":"725fb97d-243f-44aa-98d0-50d903871ae4","name":"B-0776","document_id":"0b24e8d2-e7cc-4441-abd7-337c8a2c6cf1","item_id":null,"unit_id":4,"service_category_id":"5dc2f6d2-27e0-4dac-a2b7-39080a8e0008","description":"THRUST PLATE JGE/H/K","quantity":2,"quantity_partially_received":0,"quantity_partially_shipped":0,"tax":5,"tax2":0,"discount_percent":0,"cost":878.44,"price":1010.21,"discounted_price":0,"weight":7,"modified":"2022-12-21T16:01:04+00:00","created":"2022-12-15T15:43:57+00:00","item_variations_location_id":null,"item_variation_data":null,"delete":false,"item":null},{"id":"956cf37e-3921-4cad-94bf-670cdedd2d17","name":"B-1032","document_id":"0b24e8d2-e7cc-4441-abd7-337c8a2c6cf1","item_id":null,"unit_id":4,"service_category_id":"5dc2f6d2-27e0-4dac-a2b7-39080a8e0008","description":"JGK DOOR GASKET","quantity":8,"quantity_partially_received":0,"quantity_partially_shipped":0,"tax":5,"tax2":0,"discount_percent":0,"cost":17.21,"price":19.79,"discounted_price":0,"weight":3,"modified":"2022-12-21T16:01:04+00:00","created":"2022-12-15T15:43:57+00:00","item_variations_location_id":null,"item_variation_data":null,"delete":false,"item":null},{"id":"c2b74c55-465b-4bee-84a1-6c9e8e5bd102","name":"A-0661","document_id":"0b24e8d2-e7cc-4441-abd7-337c8a2c6cf1","item_id":null,"unit_id":4,"service_category_id":"5dc2f6d2-27e0-4dac-a2b7-39080a8e0008","description":"OIL FILTER","quantity":3,"quantity_partially_received":0,"quantity_partially_shipped":0,"tax":5,"tax2":0,"discount_percent":0,"cost":24.5,"price":28.18,"discounted_price":0,"weight":4,"modified":"2022-12-21T16:01:04+00:00","created":"2022-12-15T15:43:57+00:00","item_variations_location_id":null,"item_variation_data":null,"delete":false,"item":null},{"id":"de2c8695-9589-4856-be7a-d3979a776646","name":"FREIGHT CHARGE","document_id":"0b24e8d2-e7cc-4441-abd7-337c8a2c6cf1","item_id":null,"unit_id":1,"service_category_id":"5e6a78e2-cf6c-437c-ac52-0c3a0a8e000a","description":"RE:E2920103","quantity":1,"quantity_partially_received":0,"quantity_partially_shipped":0,"tax":5,"tax2":0,"discount_percent":0,"cost":70.64,"price":95.35,"discounted_price":0,"weight":8,"modified":"2022-12-21T16:01:04+00:00","created":"2022-12-21T15:34:51+00:00","item_variations_location_id":null,"item_variation_data":null,"delete":false,"item":null},{"id":"eab3c271-20ce-4c4e-af92-8553425eaa71","name":"C-6200","document_id":"0b24e8d2-e7cc-4441-abd7-337c8a2c6cf1","item_id":null,"unit_id":4,"service_category_id":"5dc2f6d2-27e0-4dac-a2b7-39080a8e0008","description":"TOP COVER GASKET","quantity":1,"quantity_partially_received":0,"quantity_partially_shipped":0,"tax":5,"tax2":0,"discount_percent":0,"cost":345.85,"price":397.73,"discounted_price":0,"weight":1,"modified":"2022-12-21T16:01:04+00:00","created":"2022-12-13T21:21:43+00:00","item_variations_location_id":null,"item_variation_data":null,"delete":false,"item":null}]}]}

I would like to output the JSON content to look like this on my google sheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18x1cyztf5SgnKZHjqgWx2iP7SzQAksOzE_EVZoUOcy8/edit#gid=0

Any help would be greatly appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your script, when the value of `response.getContentText()` is your showing data, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
Logger.log(response.getContentText());
```

#### To:

```
Logger.log(response.getContentText());

// I added the below script.
const value = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
const addValues = [value.document[0].customer.name, value.document[0].issue_date, value.document[0].attention, value.document[0].name];
const res = value.document[0].document_items.map(o => [value.document[0].document_number, ...["name", "description", "quantity", "price", "discounted_price"].map(h => o[h]), ...addValues]);
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
```

- Please set your sheet name to `getSheetByName("Sheet1")`.
- Unfortunately, I cannot find `External PO#` you expect from your data.

Comment: Thanks Tanaike this works perfectly and now I understand how I can get other field from the JSON

Comment: Hi Tanaike just wondering on some of the invoice the value "name" is null and the name is under "item":{name} so I tried using the value from "item" instead of name but it return this value {"name=GASKET, ROCKER LEVER COVER, IHC"} is there a way that if the value in "name" is null it will instead return the value from "item":{name} but without the  name= so if value name is null it would return the value from "item":{name} the return value would like like this
GASKET, ROCKER LEVER COVER, IHC
Thanks

Comment: @Yvan L Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question in your comment, I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your new question. can I ask you about the detail of it? I would like to think of a solution to your new question by correctly understanding it.

Comment: no apology necessary thanks for all your help I will post my new issue as a new question with more detail thanks

Comment: @Yvan L Thank you for replying. I understood it. When I saw your new question, I will check it.

Answer (score 0):

### Suggestion: Clean and Extract the Required Data

The first thing I noticed is that your current script has already extracted a single JSON object from Salesbinder. However, the format returned is hard to read. You may use JSON beautify sites online to rearrange and analyze the JSON object you have produced like [JSON Viewer](https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer) (**DISCLAIMER**: I am not affiliated with the website, I just find it helpful to share it to others due to its helpful features).

### Script

Afterwards, you may be able to access the data you wanted by accessing the JSON object. For your table, you may use the following:

```
  var salesBinderInvoiceNumVal = object.document[0].document_number;
  var itemNameVal = object.document[0].document_items[0].name;
  var descriptionVal = object.document[0].document_items[0].description;
  var quantityVal = object.document[0].document_items[0].quantity;
  var priceVal = object.document[0].document_items[0].price;
  var discountPercentVal = object.document[0].document_items[0].discount_percent;
  var clientNameVal = object.document[0].customer.name;
  var issueDateVal = object.document[0].issue_date;
  var attentionVal = object.document[0].attention;
  var nameVal = object.document[0].name;
```

Note: The External PO number can't be found since there are no given values in your sample table.

But before doing so, you may want to store the generated JSON object to a variable. Thus, you may change:

```
Logger.log(response.getContentText());
```

to:

```
var object = response.getContentText();
```

Afterwards, you may add the `setValues()` function to add the values to the last row of your table. Thus, your script should be somewhat like this:

```
function fetching() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var InvNumber = sheet2.getRange('A1').getValue();
  var USERNAME = 'APIKey';
  var PASSWORD = 'x';

  var url = 'https://mydomain.salesbinder.com/api/2.0/documents.json?documentNumber=' + InvNumber + '&contextId=5';
  var headers = {
    "Authorization": "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(USERNAME + ':' + PASSWORD)
  };

  let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { headers });

  //Changes start here
  var object = response.getContentText(); //Store the JSON object to this variable
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); //get the last row

  //required values
  var salesBinderInvoiceNumVal = object.document[0].document_number;
  var itemNameVal = object.document[0].document_items[0].name;
  var descriptionVal = object.document[0].document_items[0].description;
  var quantityVal = object.document[0].document_items[0].quantity;
  var priceVal = object.document[0].document_items[0].price;
  var discountPercentVal = object.document[0].document_items[0].discount_percent;
  var clientNameVal = object.document[0].customer.name;
  var issueDateVal = object.document[0].issue_date;
  var attentionVal = object.document[0].attention;
  var nameVal = object.document[0].name;

  //add the required values to a 2d array
  var output = [[salesBinderInvoiceNumVal, itemNameVal, descriptionVal, quantityVal, priceVal, discountPercentVal, clientNameVal, issueDateVal, attentionVal, nameVal]];
  sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 1, 1, output[0].length).setValues(output); //add the 2d array to the last row of your table

}
```

### Output:

Since your script only gets the value of one cell, I assumed that it only fetches one item or one row to your table. **NOTE:** I only processed the given JSON object in your post since I have no access/account in Salesbinder. I did assume that it was the output of your current script.

[image]

### Reference:

You may further study about accessing JSON objects date in this article: [JSON Object Literals](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp)

Comment: Feel free to ask if you have questions with regards to the solution.

Comment: Hi PatrickdC thank for your suggestion when i tried it I got this error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

Comment: I do apologize for this issue. However, I did create a free account on Salesbinder but I cannot access the sample InvNumber since I cannot access items from other Salesbinder accounts. When I try to run your script, I only get `Exception: Request failed for https://mydomain.salesbinder.com returned code 404. Truncated server response: {"errors":{"error":"The record does not exist in your account."}} (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)`. This is why I assumed that the output of your script is the given JSON object in your post and assigned it to the `variable object`.

Comment: Hi PatrickdC no apology necessary i'd like to thanks you for going to all this trouble to help me I think there was something wrong with the Salesbinder site this afternoon cause at my end this afternoon it was working good then all of the sudden I was also getting the same error that you received and now it's working again using Taniake code